# Why does Spider-Man: Into the Spider-Verse have the Comics Code Authority logo at the start?

Tags: reference, spider-man-into-the-spider-verse

At the start of *Spider-man: Into the Spider-Verse* the logo for the [Comics Code Authority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comics_Code_Authority) is shown. Reading their wiki page, it seems like they have been defunct for a decade. So why is it shown now? Does it actually have any meaning?

Answer (score 5):

The CCA logo was on almost all the comics so probably it's just a wink to the older viewers of the movie who will recognize the logo almost immediately. However, there is a more obscure reference:

> The authority banned horror and monster books, keeping those
>   characters out of the Marvel universe for quite awhile. They also
>   banned depictions of drug use and gore. This eventually came to a head
>   in the pages of Amazing Spider-Man Nos. 96 and 97, when Stan Lee chose
>   to depict Harry Osborn taking LSD as an anti-drug statement. The CCA
>   refused to give him approval so he just printed the comics without
>   their stamp anyway, in a move that struck a blow large enough that the
>   authority was essentially rendered largely without authority.

[Comics Code Authority easter egg on Hollywood Reporter](https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/heat-vision/all-spider-man-spider-verse-easter-eggs-revealed-1169124)